# See terminals title when doing alt-tab

Tags: xubuntu, xfce4-terminal

I work with several terminal windows and tabs at the same time. To see logs, doing theme specific tasks, etc. I put a title on all the different tabs but when trying to find a terminal window with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> , It shows the application name rather than its window title which is the active tab title, which is quite useless.

Let's say I have terminal with following titles : **creating entities, grep, mvnw, gulp & git**. All I see is **xfce4 terminal**. Is there a way to tweak this behaviour ?

I can't put all the tabs in the same window as I need to see tabs side to side sometimes.

I'm using Xubuntu 16.04.02.

Comment: Please let me know if you have any issues with the below answer. If all works out fine, be sure to click the check mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the following below to the very bottom of your `~/.bashrc` file. There is already a section in `~/.bashrc` that starts with the title `# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir`. Comment this section out. This will automatically update the title of your terminal to the last command run. You will also want to go to Edit > Preferences > General > Title > Dynamically-set title. I have "Replaces initial title" selected from the dropdown menu. After updating this and the `~/.bashrc` you'll need to open a new terminal session for changes to take effect. Now, the dynamic title will be on the tab, the window title, the Window Button title on the panel, and the <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>tab</kbd> title.

```
# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    #PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    trap 'echo -ne "\e]0;$BASH_COMMAND\007"' DEBUG
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac
```

- `trap` assigns a command to execute at a given bash signal.
- In the `$BASH_COMMAND` you find the last command.
- You can set the terminal title with the escape sequence: `\e]0;` this is the `title\007`.
- To let the `echo` care about the backslashes give the `-e` to it.

[Source](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/3674/changing-the-terminal-title-to-the-last-shell-command)

Comment: I tested it without success. Is it normal that one line is commented ? I tried to uncomment it without any change anyway.

Comment: @AdrienH I have updated my answer starting at the second sentence above. I hope it works know. I'd be curious to know if it doesn't. Thanks

Comment: @AdrienH The commented line is the default `~/.bashrc` setting. It is actually the only line that would be different in that `case` statement.

Comment: Ok, will test on Tuesday. Don't have access to work computer atm.

Comment: Not working. I don't understand what that code is supposed to do so I can hardly say why.
Maybe we don't have the same terminal ? Preferences where under "Edit" not "Terminal".
Anyway, it would have been a nice feature but it's not worth much efforts. I can't spend time into that at the moment.

Comment: Oh, I see what it does. It adds last executed command as windows title. It's nice but it wasn't what I wanted. I still don't see window/tab title when doing `alt-tab`.

Comment: @AdrienH We have the same version of Xubuntu, the same desktop environment, and the same terminal, Xfce4 Terminal. The title should be there when doing alt-tab.  Perhaps you should try Window Manager Tweaks > Cycling > and check Cycle through windows in a list?

Comment: Ok, "Cycle through windows in a list" did it. Thanks